# How can I select channel index/root pages from an Entries Field Type?

Tags: entries-field

This seems like a somewhat overlooked feature. When I use an "Entries" field type with "All" sources selected. I don't have the option to select the root link for any of the channels. I **can** select the individual entries for the channels, just not the actual channel itself.

Is this intentional? Or is there a way to include channel index pages as a selectable option too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having thought about it a bit more, this doesn't really make much sense. Obviously the entries will only link to... entries. I got a little confused as to why it also allowed me to select "single" pages.

I still think it's worth including the option to add channel index/root pages. In the meantime, because I'm using this as a crude navigation maker, I've just created an additional single section. I then directed the Entry Template to the same directory as the index.html page. This then gives me the option to add it in my entry field, without messing any links up.

Comment: Just wanted to post this exact answer, Mark. Before adding multiple singles for your indexes and other pages like "about", "contact" etc., think about using a structure section instead. There are other good Q/As on how to set this up with entry types etc.

Comment: Thanks Carlcs, I've looked into Structures and can see the benefits. I think I avoided them because they are so similar to Channels at first glance. Thanks again.